# Weird websocket behavior: only send data when close the tab

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

have you ever encountered this weird situation. I'm playing with libwebsocket provided by warmcat.com newest version to support chrome 20. THe connection was opened correctly without any error (nothing in console log) but when I call connection.send() method of HTML5 Websocket, nothing happen (also nothing in console log). Only when I close the tab or the browser, the data is sent immediate to libwebsocket server.

I've tested in Chrome 19 and Firefox 12, the same symptom applies.

Interesting is I have a vmware guest machine which has Window XP home and Chrome 19 installed (same version as host machine, my host machine runs Windows 7). When I try HTMl5 Websocket in that guest machine, everything goes just fine @_@

Comment: Confirmed! I was just working on a websocket server in C. After writing/sending the handshake header response successfully, I attempt to send some data to the server through the browser or from the server to the browser, but nothing happens! I thought maybe I was doing something wrong and re-read the specifications for websockets but could not resolve the issue! When I saw your post, I decided to test your claim and you're right! Maybe chrome is still fuzzy with websockets.

Answer (score 2):

I have been experiencing this issue for the last 6 months or so, it started randomly one day, affecting all standard browsers on my local windows machine.

9/10 times a WebSocket connects data only flows one direction, I have tried installing many browsers and they all do the same. My only solution is to use any browser running in a linux virtual machine.

Interestingly enough, now that the latest Webkit browser that is embedded into the Source game engine has been updated, it works perfectly with WebSockets in the game (even though the Webkit Chrome is using on the same machine does not)

My only conclusion is that this is some very strange Windows bug and the only solution is to format!

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I think this bug has nothing to do with Websocket and is more likely caused by the system environment.